# Firebase toDate giving undefined error on Vue Component

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the `toDate()` function to convert a timestamp into a readable date using the `toDate()` from `firestore` and `moment.js` to convert to the desired date format.

It all looks good until I use the `toDate` function and I get an error [

> Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: member.dateAdded is undefined"

And I can't see why the error is happening since I'm using converting date on other part of my Vue component and I'm not getting this error.

Here is the component I'm getting the error. As you can see, I'm using the `toDate` before the table without problem but the one inside the table is giving me the error. When I don't use the function I get this

`Timestamp(seconds=1577548891, nanoseconds=834000000)`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar">
      <span>Player Added!</span>
      <v-btn color="blue" text @click="snackbar = false">Close</v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
    <h3 class="font-weight-medium text-center pa-3 ma-3 display-1">Member List</h3>
    <template v-if="isMember || isAdmin">
      <p
        v-for="log in logs"
        :key="log.id"
        class="body-2 text-right"
      >Last Point given @ {{log.time.toDate() | formatDate}}</p>
      <p>
        <v-simple-table fixed-header height="70vh">
          <template v-slot:default>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-left title">Name</th> 
                <th class="text-left title">Added</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="(member, index) in members" :key="index">
                <td>{{member.name}}</td>
                <td>{{member.dateAdded.toDate() | formatDate}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </template>
        </v-simple-table>
      </p>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db, fv, tstp } from "../data/firebaseInit";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import Popup from "../components/Popup";
import moment from "moment";
export default {
  components: { Popup },
  data() {
    return {
      isAdmin: false,
      isMember: false,
      snackbar: false,
      members: [],
      logs: [],
      user: null
    };
  },
  filters: {
    formatDate: function(value) {
      if (value) {
        return moment(value).format("DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm");
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchDb();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchDb() {
      db.collection("members")
        .orderBy("name")
        .onSnapshot(snap => {
          const members = [];
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            let newPlayer = doc.data();
            newPlayer.id = doc.id;
            members.push(newPlayer);
          });
          this.members = members;
          this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
        });
      db.collection("pointLog")
        .orderBy("time", "desc")
        .limit(1)
        .onSnapshot(snap => {
          const logs = [];
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            let newLog = doc.data();
            newLog.id = doc.id;
            logs.push(newLog);
          });
          this.logs = logs;
        });
    }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is the component that is adding the timestamp to the firestore

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog max-width="600px" v-model="dialog" v-if="isAdmin">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-icon color="green" x-large bottom right v-on="on">mdi-plus-circle</v-icon>
    </template>

    <v-card>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-toolbar-title>Add Player</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form>
          <v-text-field required label="Player Name" v-model="name"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn text class="success" @click="onSubmit()">Add Player</v-btn>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { db, tstp } from "../data/firebaseInit";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: null,
    };
  },
  submited: {
    name: "",
    dialog: "",
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      db.collection("members")
        .add({
          name: this.name,
          dateAdded: tstp.fromDate(new Date()),
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.dialog = false;
          this.$emit("playerAdded");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Could anyone shed my some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably because, for some elements of the `members` array, there is no `dateAdded` value.

Without seeing your data it is difficult to know what is the exact reason, but one of the most likely possible causes is documents in your `members` collection without a `dateAdded` field;

One possible way to deal with this problem is to do as follows:

```
<td v-if="member.dateAdded">{{member.dateAdded.toDate() | formatDate}}</td>
<td v-else>-</td>
```

---

In addition, note that it would be better to use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method instead of the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#on-snapshot) one, since you only want to query once the Firestore collections.

You could chain the two calls as follows:

```
fetchDb() {
  db.collection("pointLog")
    .orderBy("time", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      const logs = [];
      snap.forEach(doc => {
        let newLog = doc.data();
        newLog.id = doc.id;
        logs.push(newLog);
      });
      this.logs = logs;

      return db
        .collection("members")
        .orderBy("name")
        .get();
    })
    .then(snap => {
      const members = [];
      snap.forEach(doc => {
        let newPlayer = doc.data();
        newPlayer.id = doc.id;
        members.push(newPlayer);
      });
      this.members = members;
      this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
    });
}
```

Comment: The error was the lack of dateAdded on some documents since this was an addition. The v-if fixed the issue. On the second part of your answer, I need the onsnapshot() instead of get() because I need to keep the members array updated with changes, to help with understanding the error, I removed some code from the vue component.